# read.gct function in R. which package will support the function read.gct("file path") in R. How to read gct file in R

Tags: r

I have a gct file which I want to read in R for gene expression analysis. however the read.gct("file path") is not being recognized.
Do I need a package which supports the function. if yes then what is the package called. thanks

Comment: It looks like you might need the `CePa` package. If GCT files are plaintext, you might also be able to read them with base R's file reading functions. It'd be helpful if you could post the first few dozen rows of the file contents.

Answer (score 4):

This thread is slightly older. Anyhow, another solution is to use read.table() with no need for any other library. GCT files are just plain text files. One just has to skip the header lines:

```
dat.gct <- read.delim(file="GTEx_Analysis.gct.gz", skip=2)
```